# Different behaviour when receiving files over bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm currently developing an application for android phones which uses the buildt in [OBEX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OBject_EXchange) bluetooth service in the android phone. On my samsung S3, android version 4.0.4, the "workflow" is like this:

1. Phone A sends a file over bluetooth to my phone
2. Phone B, which is my phone, will show an AlertDialog, telling me that Phone A wants to transfer some files to my phone
3. I hit accept on this AlertDialog, and the transfer begins.

**On the other hand, if I test this with a Samsung Nexus S, android version 4.1, the "workflow" is like this:**

1. Phone A sends a file over bluetooth to my phone
2. Phone B, which is my phone, will Toast a short message telling that I have an incoming file
3. Now I have to drag down the notification bar to accept the incoming file

Is there anyway I can change this behaviour? So that the AlertDialog, explain in the first case always appears, without dragging the notification bar down?

Is this a vendor issue, or android version issue?

Is it possible to always accept incoming files from a paired device, without rooting the phone?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It may be the vendor issue as different vendors does customization on the OPP(Obex ) usecase, look into file BluetoothOppIncomingFileConfirmActivity.java or other files  in platform/packages/apps/Bluetooth/src/com/android/bluetooth/opp/